# What does the --size parameter of Xrandr do?

Tags: xrandr, size

After connecting a secondary display by VGA, I tried to change the resolution of that display so it would be closer to the size of my primary (laptop) display. For this, I thought to try the `--size` option of xrandr:
`-s <size>/<width>x<height> or --size <size>/<width>x<height>`

So I tried these two commands, but nothing changed at all with either of these. As that might mean I use `--size` wrong, my question is: What does `--size` do?

Commands and output:

```
[Me ~]$ xrandr --output LVDS  --auto --primary --output VGA-0 --size 1366x768 --left-of LVDS
[Me ~]$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2966 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1280x720      59.86  
   1152x768      59.78  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
VGA-0 connected 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 275mm
   1600x1200     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
[Me ~]$ xrandr --output LVDS  --auto --primary --output VGA-0 --size 1280x1024 --left-of LVDS
[Me ~]$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2966 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1280x720      59.86  
   1152x768      59.78  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
VGA-0 connected 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 275mm
   1600x1200     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
[Me ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new mode for the resolution you want.

Use `cvt 1366 768`, the output is something like this:

```
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Then use:

```
> xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
> xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1368x768_60.00"
```

And finally you can set it:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

Comment: This does what I want, but a little more information on what `cvt` is wouldn't hurt. ;)